# Jquery UI in IE10

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, internet-explorer

I have this code on my system, and it works very well in all "real browsers", but now I need put this working on IE10.

Because this development is inside a CMS I can't do upgrade on Jquery or UI. The $ version is 1.3.2 an UI version is 1.7.3.

In IE I don't receive any message of error. And the Items with a class = "container myDevelopment" aren't sortables.

Some one know what it's doesn't work?

```
$(".container.myDevelopment").sortable({
        connectWith: ".container.myDevelopment",
        receive: function (event, ui) {

            var issuecode = ui.item.attr("id");
            var issueStatus = this.getAttribute("data-status");

           alert("it's works");
        }

    }).disableSelection();
```

Comment: the function sortable

Comment: can you remove the `.disableSelection()` and check whether it is working

Comment: and the `alert()` has a syntax issue, hopefully it is not there in the actual code

Comment: The alert isn't a problem, and without .disableSelection() doen't work as well.

Comment: You can't hope to use modern browsers with old scripting technologies. Find a way to upgrade jQuery / jQueryUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think IE has a problem with the detection of the event. *Mouse drag interactions start and then get cancelled right away, this has the appearance of no jQuery UI drag-and-drop mouse interaction at all*.

For more detail see this post: 
http://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-does-not-work-on-ie9

It is a bit old but may help.